# PHP5 shared (apache2 & cli) configuration

Tags: apache2, php, configuration

I need to set the `date.timezone` setting in my PHP5 configuration. Obviously I could simply edit the `php.ini` files (both `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`), but that doesn't feel like a very good solution, for two reasons:

- The timezone setting will be the same in all environments, so I would prefer to set it in a single location instead of having to edit multiple files.
- I would like to symlink `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` to the ones located in `/usr/share/php5`, so I stay up-to-date with changes that come with package updates.

The solution I have in mind is to add a .ini file to `/etc/php5/mods-available` with my configuration and then run `sudo php5enmod my-config` to create symlinks from `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d` and `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d`, but this is probably intended for modules and not for custom configuration. Are there any downsides to this approach? Will this allow me to override settings that are already set in the main `php.ini`?

Why isn't there a `conf-available` and `conf-enabled` structure as there is for Apache?